# What is a ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: angular, es6-promise

I am using angular 6. One of the http calls returns a `ZoneAwarePromise` when I try to convert the `Observable` into a `Promise`. Also the then block is not getting called.

```
const login = this.authService.login(email, password).toPromise()
login.then(() => {\* not getting called*\})
```

Can someone explain what is a `ZoneAwarePromise` ?

Comment: did you find out how to make the then block getting called?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Angular relies heavily on zone.js to persist an execution context across asynchronous tasks. It's wrapped up in an injectable service called `NgZone`.

These Zones wrap up common JS objects meant to run async tasks, which include Promises. This is maintained in a `Zone` as a Task, MicroTask, etc.

A `ZoneAwarePromise` is still functionally identical to a normal Promise, but internally stays aware of a `Zone`'s execution context, and the `Zone` can know when that Promise completes.

In Angular, this execution context almost always means running change detection.

Comment: It's not functionally identical, because `.finally` is broken :p

Comment: didn't understand anything, but yeah, looks like you're right. :)

Answer (score 8):

We use Angular because we can only change model and it will update view automatically for us, based on declarative templates that we provide via metadata.

The way Angular handles this is by intercepting three types of events:

- user events (like clicks),
- clocks (`setTimeout`, `setInterval`) and
- network (`fetch`, XHR, `HttpClient`).

Interally, this is done via **zones**. When you load `setTimeout`, it actually swaps the default `setTimeout` implementation with its own implementation, but with the same signature. When you call `setTimeout`, you're not even aware that you're using zones.

On a very high-level, it pretty much works like this:

```
const originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout
window.setTimeout = (fn, time) => {
  originalSetTimeout(() => { fn(); updateView() }, time)
}
```

It pretty much just executes your function as usual and then calls another thing -- which is used by Angular do update the view.

`ZoneAwarePromise` is just a way to use `Promise` so that zone is *aware* of it. You can find implementation details in source code of Zone.js, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 2):

Promise is a constructor that at run time in the browser resolves to `ZoneAwarePromise()` from `zone.js`. Please visit the following [link](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1429) to get more insights.